# I want to replace my current selenium generated xlsx file with csv

Tags: java, selenium, csv, selenium-webdriver

I have one automation program which goes through webpages and returns the desired result in xlsx format.

I want to replace this xlsx with csv.

Comment: Can you upgrade your question? on the [ask] page you'll find some info how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are two very nice Apache libraries for this purpose.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi : Apache POI for reading/writing to a .xslx file (and many other Microsoft office file formats), and

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv : Apache Commons CSV for reading/writing to a .csv file.

Example code, to read the xlsx:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook(file);
Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);  // get first sheet
Iterator<Row> iterator = sheet.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = iterator.next().iterator();
    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell c = cellIterator.next();
        // add to data structure
    }
}
```

And to write the CSV:

```
String[][] data; // loaded from XLSX
CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(new File("output.csv"), CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
printer.printRecord("Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3");  // print header

for (String[] strings : data) {
    printer.printRecord(strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
}
```